# Feature Request: scroll up button

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are a lot of web-sites that use this feature. It is quite a common thing for "long" sites. I see the following scenario for SO:

1. You open the question and quickly read it
2. You scroll down to look through the all answers to make sure nobody has proposed your answer/solution
3. You scroll up to read the question more detailed for giving a best answer

Thus, at the 3rd phase this button might be extremally usefull.

Comment: Just press `Home` button for the same in Windows.

Comment: Press and hold `Shift` + `Space` also works fine.

Answer (score 2):

A quick workaround would be to simply press the <kbd>Home</kbd> button on the keyboard.

It works for all browsers for Windows and Linux (haven't tried Mac).

---

If you don't want to use the keyboard, drag the scrollbar upwards.

Comment: Yes, it is true. But what if you used mouse for scrolling question down. It would be great do not move your hand from mouse to keybouard and just click the button.

Comment: @VladimirKostyukov Move your pointer to the top of the scroll bar and click (hold) there. Back to top, no keyboard necessary.

Comment: @AsheeshR: Not really, it just scrolls up for a bit. I'll work on a userscript later today.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Click and hold for a second.

Comment: @VladimirKostyukov grab the scrollbar and drag it upwards